# How to enable deep linking for unity game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, android-app-indexing

How to enable deep linking for unity game? i have followed all google developer site steps and it is working for me in Android app .

Comment: you mean it is NOT

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the [App indexing guide](https://developers.google.com/app-indexing/android/app) to support intent filter and adding web-app association?

MB

Comment: Yes i have followed .. and currently deep linking is working for an android app .. but in Unity game app it is crashing i saw the adb it is showing Didn't find MainActivity class ..

Comment: Better check with unity on how to enable deeplinking in unity game.

Comment: Hi mia i am getting an error -java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/appindexing/AppIndex      i included the google-play-services library still it is showing me this error .

Answer (score 0):

When we import a Jar filefrom android studio ,if we have created a java class with extending AppCompat activity or any other Activity, unity will not find the that Activity , it is necessary to extend the java class with UnityPlayerActivity . for that we need to include PlayBackEngines/AndroidPlayer/variations/il2cpp/developement/classes/classes.jar
copy this jar file and past it in Android studios Lib folder.